# RailsTutorial.org book design question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, view, local-variables

Hi I worked through Michael Hartl's RAILSTUTORIAL book and I have a question about how he builds the user's show page.

The page is supposed to list all the posts a user has made.

### UsersController

```
def show
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
   @posts = @user.posts.paginate(:per_page => "10",:page => params[:page])
   @title = @user.name
 end
```

### users/show.html.erb

```
<table class="profile" summary="Profile information">
  <tr>
<td class="main">
  <h1><%= @user.name %></h1>
  <%= render 'follow_form' if user_signed_in? %>
    <% unless @user.posts.empty? %>
      <table class="posts" summary="User posts">

           <%= render @posts %> # this goes to posts/_post and sends the object as post
                            # that makes the _post view use a local variable correct?
          </table>              # is there a way to do with with an @post variable?
    <%= will_paginate @posts %>
  <% end %>
 </td>
 <td class="sidebar round">
  <%= link_to avatar_for(@user), @user.avatar.url %><br />
  <strong>Name</strong> <%= @user.name %><br />
  <strong>URL</strong>  <%= link_to user_path(@user), user_path(@user) %>
  <strong>Posts</strong> <%= @user.posts.count %>
  <%= render 'shared/stats' %>
</td>   
   </tr>    
 </table>
```

### posts/_post.html.erb

```
<tr>
  <td class="post">
 <span class="title"><strong><%= link_to post.title, post %></strong></span><br />

 <span class="timestamp">
  Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(post.created_at) %> ago. </span>
    <a href="<%= likers_post_path(@post) %>">Likers</a><span id="likers"><br />
</span>

  </td>

  <% if current_user?(post.user)%>
    <td>
      <%= link_to "delete", post, :method => :delete,
                                     :confirm => "You sure?",
                                     :title => post.content %>
    </td>
  <%end%>
</tr>
```

I need to render a partial in the users view that uses the post object, but it asks for it as @post and since no @post has been defined in the show action of the user's controller I get a nil error.

It seem odd to me to go from the user's controller to the posts view and use a local variable, which if I understand local variables correctly can't be used outsider that view. Is there a way to assign the value of post in that view to @post in the users view?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Please point us at the section where this is happening so that we can debug the same things that you are.

Comment: I worked this out by using local variable and passing it to the other views, and when I do have @post defined I send that as the local. If you have time to debug something else I've asked a new question here about how to go from the rails tutorial book to nested routes and keep the feed intact. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800399/railstutorial-org-book-changing-to-nested-routes

Comment: But incase you did want to see this, its Listing 11.17 in this chapter, http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/user-microposts#top There's basically no explanation to it, and I don't know another way to get it done so I've kept it with a local variable. And should I switch to the example below instead of <%= render @posts %> and do it the long code way because that will render faster??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a local variable in the partial, and assign it in the `locals` hash. This line is a shortcut for iterating through the array and rendering the partial. I'm not sure if this works anymore in Rails 3:

```
<%= render @posts %>
```

The way I would do it:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <%= render 'posts/post', :post => post %>
<% end %>
```

The slightly older way of rendering partials:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <%= render :partial => 'posts/post', :locals => {:post => post} %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: <%= render @posts %> works in Rails 3 just fine and does exactly what your second example does, except will take a little while longer to render.